# How to configure integration test for the new Spring for GrapQL

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, integration-testing

I am currently learning Spring for GraphQL and am working on an application to do some basic CRUD operations, using the GraphQL API using Spring-boot with JPA and an H2 in-memory database for testing. Now I am trying to write some integration tests using the GraphlQlTester interface. There is a possibility to test importing just the service layer, storing the data in a collection at this layer. Now I want to be able to access the repository layer too to temporarily store and manipulate the test data in the h2 database. I have been researching the [documentation online](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/testing.html#testing-requests), but unfortunately, I have not found any possible way to approach this particular issue. Perhaps you may have an idea?

Entity Class

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @Table(name = "address")
    public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private int postCode;
    }
```

Controller Class (just the first method)

```
     @Controller
     @RequiredArgsConstructor
     public class AddressController {
        private final AddressService addressService;

        private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Address with id %d not found";

        @QueryMapping
        List<Address> findAllAddresses() {
            return addressService.findAll();
        }
```

Service Class (just the first method)

```
    @Service
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class AddressService {
        private final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Address with id %d not found";
        private final AddressRepository addressRepository;
    
        private final ContactInformationRepository contactInformationRepository;
    
        public List<Address> findAll() {
            return addressRepository.findAll();
        }
```

Repository

```
    public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {
    }
```

Integration Test class

```
    import com.soscarlos.dropit.entity.Address;
    import com.soscarlos.dropit.repository.AddressRepository;
    import com.soscarlos.dropit.service.AddressService;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.graphql.GraphQlTest;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.GraphQlTester;
    
    @GraphQlTest(AddressController.class)
    @Import({AddressService.class, AddressRepository.class})
    class AddressControllerTest {
    
        @Autowired
        GraphQlTester tester;
    
        @Autowired
        AddressService addressService;
    
        @Autowired
        AddressRepository addressRepository;
    
        @Test
        void findAllAddresses() {
        //        language=GraphQL
            String document = """
                    query {
                    findAllAddresses {
                                    id
                                    street
                                    city
                                    postCode
                                    }
                    }
    
                    """;
    
            tester.document(document)
                    .execute()
                    .path("findAllAddresses")
                    .entityList(Address.class)
                    .hasSize(1);
        }
```

I cannot load the application context because of this error basically

"Error creating bean with name 'com.soscarlos.dropit.repository.AddressRepository': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.soscarlos.dropit.repository.AddressRepository]: Specified class is an interface"

Comment: You can refer my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76833620/graphqltester-or-graphqltesttemplate-is-not-getting-injected-with-springboot-3-x/77216264#77216264

Answer (score 0):

As this version of GraphQL is totally integrated with Spring Boot, you must remove that `@Import` annotation.