# GraphQlTester or GraphQLTestTemplate is not getting injected With SpringBoot 3.x

Tags: graphql, spring-boot-test, graphql-java

```
SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureGraphQlTester
class SpaceControllerTest {

@Autowired
private GraphQlTester graphQlTester;
```

// below the test cases`

---

**Throwing exception** : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'graphQlTester': No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.GraphQlTester' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I tried working on various options but not getting it injected in Sprinboot3.x .
Any link to guide how to make it work with Springboot 3.x would help. Thankyou`

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem with Spring Boot 3. I found another way to test the controller in one of the code repositories on github. Instead of using GraphQlTester I have used HttpGraphQlTester. Here is my sample controller

```
package com.ms.springgraphql.controller;

import com.ms.springgraphql.model.Book;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.HttpGraphQlTester;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class BookControllerTest {

    private HttpGraphQlTester graphQlTester;

    @LocalServerPort
    int port;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        WebTestClient client = WebTestClient.bindToServer()
                .baseUrl(String.format("http://localhost:%s/graphql", port))
                .build();

        graphQlTester = HttpGraphQlTester.create(client);
    }

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertNotNull(graphQlTester);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnBook(){

        //given
        // language=GraphQL
        String document = """
            query {
              findOne(id: 1){
                pages
                rating
                title
              }
            }
""";
        //when
        graphQlTester.document(document)
                .variable("id", 1)
                .execute()
                .path("findOne")
                .entity(Book.class)
                .satisfies(book -> {
                            assertEquals("The Great Novel", book.getTitle());
                            assertEquals(300,book.getPages());
                        });
    }
}
```